# Cumulative n_distinct with condition for group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to build a column containing the group's cumulative number of distinct URLs that were visited at least twice. How do I do that?

My data frame looks something like this:

```
ID Link                 RevisitedPages
1  example.org          0
1  example.org/whatever 0
1  example.org/blank    0
1  example.org/whatever 1
1  example.org/whatever 1
1  example.org/blank    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use the following:

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Link) %>% 
  mutate(RevisitedPages = 1 * (row_number() == 2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% mutate(RevisitedPages = cumsum(RevisitedPages))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
#      ID Link                 RevisitedPages
#   <int> <fct>                         <dbl>
# 1     1 example.org                       0
# 2     1 example.org/whatever              0
# 3     1 example.org/blank                 0
# 4     1 example.org/whatever              1
# 5     1 example.org/whatever              1
# 6     1 example.org/blank                 2
```

In this way we first look at every (ID, Link) pair and put 1 to the second visit, if exists. Then grouping by ID alone we use cumsum.